# Deployment of Kubernetes failed due to the error in image pull

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-cloud

I'm trying to deploy Docker image in Kubernetes. When I created deployments and services deployments, pods and replica set were failed showing the message bellow (in minikube).

[image: Deployments failed]

[image: Pods failed]

I tried Docker login in power shell. However that doesn't work. As I can understand it's a problem of loading file in docker cloud.

Anyone have an idea about how to resolve this....

Comment: Could you provide your deployment yaml to understand where the problem is, because now it looks like minikube tried to pull `kubertest_test1_1` image from dockerhub and, of course,  it could not pull it and failed with the error.

Comment: Finally I figure out what's the problem. It's because wrong image name in `*.yaml` file. I was looking for a quick fix. However after questions asked by you guys, I went through the documentation A-Z. After that I was able to find the answer.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What docker images are you trying to use?

From the error message `kubertest_test1_1` and `kubertest_test2_1` images certainly does not exist.

Comment: I'm using .net core 2 docker images. `kubertest_test1_1` and `kubertest_test2_1` are containers made from that.